Run PowerShell Script With Large Font Size
I want to run a powershell script with customized console properties without changing the default properties.
I know the default font size is too small for me (14).
I can change it permanently in Properties.
But, I just want to run the PS1 file with a larger font size (28) temporarily, without changing the default settings.
This my ps1 file for example:
$FontSize = 28
# Set Console font Size ???
Write-Host $FontSize
pause

What code do I need for that purpose?
